# Set SP.UI.Status or SP.UI.Notify at PostBack

Tags: javascript, postback

I use in my web part a `Session[""]` and would like to notify the user when the session is expired. I check at the `PostBack` event if the session is already okay, if not, I will execute a JS function which shows the `SP.UI.Status` warning message.

Now I don’t know how I could execute the JS. I tested it the `ScriptManager`, but then I get a error, that the `SP.UI.Status` is not define. 
How could I add the `SP.UI.Status` at the PostBack?

[Edit]

The same issue occurs with SP.UI.Notify and is fixed with the same solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess for the reason you are having trouble with calling SP.UI.Status.addStatus is because the SP.js script file (which contains the namespace and relevant functions) is loaded on demand.

In order to call SP.UI.Status.addStatus() as soon as the page loads, you'll need to make sure you use the script on demand framework for doing so.

Something like this

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(mysessionexpiredfunction, 'sp.js')

Comment: That exactly what I mean! I didn’t know anything about the `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded()` method. I could solved it with: `this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "test", "ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(test, 'sp.js');", true);`. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to check if the session has expired client side onclick(). Then it's merely a function call to the [SP.UI.Status.addStatus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410028.aspx)

If that's not possible, there are some alternatives I've used with various success in the past. You could e.g. try to use Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>SP.UI.Status.addStatus();</script>"); like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171230/calling-javascript-from-server-side).

Comment: Mhm how should that work? Output is not a method. I tried it with `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "test", "test();", true);` but here i get following error: `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'addStatus': object is null or undefined`. I think at that point, the `SP.UI.Status.addStatus` is not ready, right? If I executed the function with a test button everything works fine.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. If you have to do it serverside, Paul Lucas' method is better.

Answer (score 0):

When function with parameters view:

[Pass parameters in ExecuteOrDelayuntilScriptLoaded in Javascript client Object model](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39731/pass-parameters-in-executeordelayuntilscriptloaded-in-javascript-client-object-m)

You can use an function as a delegate and then call your function with in.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () { alertThis("Hello World") }, "core.js");

function alertThis(value)
{
    alert(value);
}
```