# Pass parameters in ExecuteOrDelayuntilScriptLoaded in Javascript client Object model

Tags: client-object-model

I have written a javascript client-object model code and I am calling it through the below line code from content editor webpart:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebSiteData(sys), "sp.js");// throwing error
```

But it is throwing javascript error in init.js and other javascript functions are not working. Can someone tell me how to pass parameters to javascript client-model function?

Comment: Why don't you like to have your code as code formatted? In my option this makes the question clear.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use an function as a delegate and then call your function with in.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () { alertThis("Hello World") }, "core.js");

function alertThis(value)
{
    alert(value);
}
```

It is worth reading about closures, delegates and Anonymous functions in javascript to help understand the code.
[SO - How does an anonymous function in javascript work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/how-does-an-anonymous-function-in-javascript-work)
[SO - How do javascript closures work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)
[Mozzila Developer Network Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

Any comments to help improve this answer would be helpful.

Comment: Fixed Line breaks between links.

Comment: @Vardhaman I still want to find a good MDN link for anonymous functions as its is more on topic

Answer (score 2):

The answer suggested by JC Vivian works nicely, but in my opinion there's a cleaner, more readable way. You can create a function that returns the function that does what you need:

```
function dataGetterFor (param) {
    return function () {
        getWebSiteData(param);
    };
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(dataGetterFor(sys), "sp.js");
```

This causes `dataGetterFor(sys)` to be evaluated and `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` to be called with an anonymous function. A shorter but less extensible way to achieve the same result is the one-liner

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () { getWebSiteData(sys); }, "sp.js");
```