# change title of a modal window

Tags: development, javascript

how can I change the title of a modal window open through the command using?

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () { openModalWindow('.....')},\"sp.js\");
```

I would like the person to see: loading ...

and at the end of the loading to then show the true title of the page.

---

This solution sets the title of the modal window, I would like to change the title after the window has been opened.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can find the same question here:

[Pass parameters in ExecuteOrDelayuntilScriptLoaded in Javascript client Object model](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39731/pass-parameters-in-executeordelayuntilscriptloaded-in-javascript-client-object-m)

To make changes to the title like so in JavaScript:

```
var win = window.open();

win.document.title="......Change Me......";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you plan on loading your modal dialog, but usually you can just do as below:

```
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
options.url = "url to the page";
options.title = "Modal Dialog Title Here";

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

Which then would make yours look something like this:

```
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
options.url = "url to the page";
options.title = "Modal Dialog Title Here";

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () { SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);},"sp.js");
```

Comment: I would like to change the title of modaldialog once the page in dialog is fully charged.

Answer (score -1):

Simonw pass the title like so:

```
<a href="#" onclick="openDialog('Test.aspx?ID={@ID}','{$title}'); return true "/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function openDialog(FormPath,Title) {
    var options = {
        url: FormPath,
        width: 950,
        height: 800,
        title: Title,
        allowMaximize:'true'

    };
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps