# Cannot read property 'get_current' of undefined

Tags: client-object-model

I am using this code:

```
"use strict"
var BasicJSOM = window.BasicJSOM || {};
BasicJSOM.Crud = BasicJSOM.Crud || {};

$(function() {
   BasicJSOM.Crud.MainDemo = new BasicJSOM.Crud.Main();
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(BasicJSOM.Crud.MainDemo.readListItems("pages"), "SP.js");   
  });


 BasicJSOM.Crud.Main= function(){

    function _readListItems(library){

       var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       var targetList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(library);
       var query = new SP.CamelQuery();
        var listItems = targetList.getItems();

        results = context.loadQuery(listItems);
        context.executeQueryAsync(_onSucceed, _Fail);

       function _onSucceed(){
            alert("Success"); 

       }

       function _Fail(){
       alert("fail"); 
       }

    }//end of read list


    return {
readListItems: _readListItems    
    }

 }
```

But the error am having is about the SP.js is not loaded, I am using jQuery to wait for page load, then using `SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify a function as the first parameter of the `executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` method, like `BasicJSOM.Crud.MainDemo.readListItems`. If you use `BasicJSOM.Crud.MainDemo.readListItems("pages"),` the function is executed immediately, that means probably before the `SP.js` library loaded.

If you need to pass a parameter to the method, use the following syntax:

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () { BasicJSOM.Crud.MainDemo.readListItems("pages") }, "SP.js");
```

See [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39731/pass-parameters-in-executeordelayuntilscriptloaded-in-javascript-client-object-m) as reference.

Comment: Thanks @pholpar, do I need to use `SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` or just right away executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded, what's the difference? Also do I have to use executeFunc?

Comment: See this thread for details: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58503/sp-sod-how-to-use-correctly